# Unable to create List object in powershell

Tags: list, powershell

I am trying to create list in power shell using below statements

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$list= @()
#list.Add($MonitorName);
```

Cannot convert value to type "System.Collections.ArrayList". Only core types are supported in this language mode.

Please provide the solution,Thanks in advance

Solution:

```
$list= @()
$list += "aaa"
$list += "bbb"
```

etc can be used to create the list in language constraint mode

Comment: Try `$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()`

Comment: Your session is running in constrained language mode, what value do you get from `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode` ?

Comment: Yes, I am in constrained language mode what I should change?

Comment: Is this issue you have from a company computer or server? If so, they might have enabled constrained mode thru policy and there is not much you can do about it other than talking with your company IT security department to remove it

Comment: is there any other way to create list

Answer (score 1):

How we use lists in powershell:

```
# Init:
$list = "element 1", "element 2", "element 3" #or
$list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList #or
$list = @()

# Adding elements
$list.Add("element 1") #or
$list += ("element 2")

# Display elements
$list #or
$list[int e.g. 0, 1, 2..4] #or
$list | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }
```

Comment: I would just add that when describing the use of `+=` to add new elements to an array, you should point out that the entire array is actually being recreated. For small tasks this won't matter, but it could have a huge impact on performance in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following example

```
# Create a new list of numbers
$list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[int]

# Add items to the list
$list.Add(1)
$list.Add(2)
$list.Add(3)

# Display the list
$list
```